# Getting triple output from Python script

Tags: python, pandas, gpx

Very new to Python - I'm modifying a script I found so I can scrape location information from a site, convert to .gpx and then use in navigation software. Managed to get everything to work well, I'm just getting the output three times! Would someone be able to point me in the right direction as to why this is happening? I'm sure it's something really obvious, but I can't figure it out at all.

Code as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from time import gmtime, strftime
import dateutil.parser as dparser
from dateutil import tz
from datetime import timezone

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
skippers=[]
rankings=[]
latitudes=[]
longitudes=[]

driver.get("https://www.vendeeglobe.org/en/ranking")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

# get time of position of report and do some stuff to make sure it is recognised as 24hour clock and UTC
filetime = soup.find('p', class_=('rankings__subtitle'))
# print(filetime)
filetime  = re.sub(r"[h\(\)]+", ' ', filetime.text)
# print(filetime)
filetime = dparser.parse(filetime, fuzzy=True)
# print(filetime)
filetime = filetime.strftime("%y%m%d%H%M")


# find the entries for each boat and interate through them extracting what we want
for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'rankings__item'}):
    name=a.find('span', attrs={'style':'max-width: 140px;'})  # boat name
    ranking=a.find('li', attrs={'class':'rankings__number'})  # current postion in fleet
 # the location of lat and lon is not obvious, and nested, so locate by the position of respective LI
    list = a.findAll('li')[6]
    lat = list.findAll('span')[1]
    lon = list.findAll('span')[2]
# Convert lat and lon to strings and strip  special characters    
    lat = re.sub(r"\W+|_", " ", lat.text)
    lon = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ' ', lon.text)
    # covert degrees mins and seconds to decimal degrees
    deg, minutes, seconds, direction =  re.split('[ ]', lat)
    lat = (float(deg) + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/(60*60)) * (-1 if direction in ['O', 'S'] else 1)
    lat = round(lat, 4)
    deg, minutes, seconds, direction =  re.split('[ ]', lon)
    lon = (float(deg) + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/(60*60)) * (-1 if direction in ['O', 'S'] else 1)
    lon = round(lon, 4)
# Append the boats numbers to the  list 
    skippers.append(name.text)
    rankings.append(ranking.get_text(strip=True))
    latitudes.append(lat)
    longitudes.append(lon)

# create a pandas data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id':skippers,'latitude':latitudes,'longitude':longitudes})

# Format information
def to_gpx(df, filename=None, mode='w'):
    def row_to_gpx(row):
        xml = ['<gpx>']
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            xml.append('<wpt lat="{0}" lon="{1}"><name>{2}</name></wpt>'.format(latitudes[i], longitudes[i], skippers[i]))
        xml.append('</gpx>')
        return '\n'.join(xml)
    res = '\n'.join(df.apply(row_to_gpx))

# Output to .gpx
    if filename is None:
        return res
    with open(filename, mode) as f:
          f.write(res)

pd.DataFrame.to_gpx = to_gpx

df.to_gpx('Scheds_'+filetime+'.gpx')
```

The output I'm getting is along the lines of:

```
<gpx>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
</gpx>
<gpx>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
</gpx>
<gpx>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
<wpt lat="000000" lon="000000"><name>Name</name></wpt>
</gpx>
```

I'd expect just one block of waypoints between gpx tags, but I'm getting three!

Thanks all.

Comment: I suggest try running the scraping part, you might be getting three copies of the result from the site. BTW, how do you run the script?

Comment: hey! I've run just the scraping part and printing it to console - I get each iteration of the data as it scrapes the website. There's 33 bits of data so it runs 33 times and adds the next data point each time. I'm running it from terminal on MacOS

Comment: If the scraping part outputs just once, then save it to a file and replace all the scraping parts with that load. Shrink your code the same way until you find the error. Doesn't look like something that sticks out to me.